# Azure Pipeline / Docker Container - an error occurred during the pre-login handshake

Tags: c#, sql-server, docker, dockerfile, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to run integration tests in my Azure pipeline that connects to a SQL Server in a docker container, but receiving the following error in the pipeline:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Success)

Searching on Google, I found that this error occurs if you don't have the `TrustServerCertificate=True` in your connection string, however, I don't have a "normal" connection string to the SQL Server since I connect to the SQL Server service through the docker file

```
RUN /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr --accept-eula & sleep 20 \
&& /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P '********' -i /opt/mssql-scripts/*.sql \
&& pkill sqlservr
```

Is there a docker command for setting the `TrustServerCertificate` to true?

Comment: It looks like you're executing `sqlcmd` inside the Docker container. Where are you getting the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` from? What's the connection string you're using there?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly (I'm a junior developer and I didn't build the script myself), but I'm getting the exception when running the integration tests in the pipeline. I thought the connection string was the one I posted in the code snippet in my question, where would the connection string you mention be located, in the docker file or the docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: Most likely the SqlException is coming from a .NET Core or .NET 5/6/7 application that's getting invoked from your pipeline as defined in its .yaml/.yml file. That .NET application should have an appsettings.json file and the connection string should be in there.

Comment: Aha, now I understand, yes there is a "testsettings.json" files in the integration test project, and in that file there is a sql connection string:
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "****************": "Server=localhost,14330;Database=*******;User Id=SA;Password=****************;TrustServerCertificate=True;"

Comment: I added the "TrustServerCertificate=True;" parameter on there but still the same error in the pipline:

[11:55:23 ERR] An error occurred using the connection to database '******' on server 'localhost,14330'.
[11:55:23 ERR] An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type '************.Data.UserDbContext'.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Success)

Comment: have your tried adding Encrypt=false to your connection string?

Comment: When adding "Encrypt=false" to the connection string I get another error:
System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (Connection refused)) (The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: TestFixture fixture)
---- System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (Connection refused)
-------- System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Connection refused
------------ System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : Connection refused
---- The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: TestFixture fixture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was I had not built all containers in my pipeline, I had used the azure pipeline task DockerCompose@0 with action `Run a specific service`, so only 1 of my 3 services was built, solution was to change to action `Run services` which builds all services